# Read lines until find specific characters

Tags: python, filereader

I'm trying to read a file (reading every line in this file, with letters, numbers and characters). The script needs to work generally and the files will be similar but with some changes.

Now it reads when it finds a line looks like this: "**HWCOLOR COMP 1066 30". I need that the script read all lines until it finds " **HW ". The script below is working for first problem explained.

How can the script be written to read the file until it finds "**HW" and stops there?

I tried to replace '**HWCOLOR COMP 1066 30" with **HW" but it won't work, because all characters don't match.

```
data = [] 

with open('valvebody_nodes_rec.txt') as f:
    # Skips text before the beginning of the interesting block:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == '*NODE, SYSTEM=R':
            break    

    # Reads text until the end of the block:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == '**HWCOLOR COMP       1066    30':
            break
        data.append([x.strip() for x in line.split(',')])   #intersect text
```

Comment: did you try using : if line.startswith("**HW"): as the condition

Comment: Do the lines _begin_ with the strings you are looking for? Are they the only content on the line?

Comment: @Kenstars Never thought about it. I will try.

Comment: @pstatix Only content on the line. That line will always start with "**HW ...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using a regular expression instead of string match.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

```
match = re.search('your regex here', line)
if match:
    ...
```

If you aren't familiar with regular expressions, go find a tutorial and once you know the basics play some [Regex Golf](https://alf.nu/RegexGolf).  Regular expressions are extremely powerful and useful, so I'd strongly recommend learning them.

Alternatively, you could also do something like

```
if line.strip().startswith('**HW'):
```

or

```
if '**HW' in line:
```

Comment: The second part of your answer worked for me. I will look forward with your recommendation. Thanks.